# Is the crypto riot.im claims to use safe?

Tags: encryption, protocol-analysis

My friends want to communicate with me using *“about.riot.im”*, I tried to research them and the protocols they claim to use and I only found their own websites promoting it, so the whole thing seems sketchy to me.

> Matrix provides state-of-the-art end-to-end encryption as a
>   first-class citizen using the Olm and Megolm cryptographic ratchets.

I tried googling for that Olm and Megolm encryption and the whole thing seems sketchy to me.

Can anyone here confirm that the cryptography and implementation they use are sound and safe? And that you can trust riot.im?

Comment: I think the purple's very convincing  and I like it, but I'll stick to my one time pads.  Have you read http://matrix.org/docs/guides/e2e_implementation.html?  They purport to use elliptic curves and AES.

Comment: Actually, have you tried just Googling some of this???  See https://www.nccgroup.trust/globalassets/our-research/us/public-reports/2016/november/ncc_group_olm_cryptogrpahic_review_2016_11_01.pdf which took 2 minutes.  Grrr.

Comment: @PaulUszak Can they be trusted? I'm no expert, but just seem too shady to google something like "olm encryption" and have no relevant top results that aren't from matrix or riot itself

Comment: Olm seems to be an implementation of some of the algorithms Signal uses, which have been well reviewed.

Comment: While the algos have been reviewed, there's no guarantee that riot.im implemented them correctly. Analyzing their implementation would be off-topic at Crypto.SE. Yet, you can find related analysis online. Besides that, *“Can they be trusted?”* is rather subjective… as every person has individual parameters where his/her trust starts and ends. Also, individual scenarios play a big part in “trust“ assessment. If it's just you and your friends chatting and if riot.im implemented everything correctly, it should be safe enough to use. If you face a nation state adversary, it may not be good enough.